# Matrix factorization on implicit feedback score. How should i do it?

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a group recommender system.

i have feedback score in this format

1.023400000000000087e+00 1.005066999999999950e+02 5.539999999999999786e-02

where the last two digits  after the plus sign depict user and item individually. HOW should i pass this information through the recommendation engine to get meaningful results ?

Comment: This question is totally unclear. It needs more detail.

Comment: I am trying to create a group recommender system in python but am totally lost, I have feedbackscores to start with that have been obtained from implicit data. how should I go about it  ? Some details about the intended system are

It is a user group-post recommendation engine.
I plan to be using Matrix factorization after grouping the users to receive recommendations .

Comment: This question is very confusing and may be hard to answer. Either you have implicit feedback in meaning of the event, like click, view, etc. or you have a explicit score. If score is somehow conducted form implicit events, it would be good to mention it here and how it's calculated. Also "the last two digits after plus sign" -> hard to get how to interpret even this single line example. Would be good to edit the question to make it more clear.